# SpeechSynthesizer doesn't get all installed voices

Tags: c#, .net, speech-recognition, text-to-speech

I have installed a new 32 bits Scansoft voice (Jennifer) in my Windows 7 64 bits OS in order to be able to use from in one .NET application i'm developing.

The problem is that I when I call the method :

```
   List<string> allInstalledVoices = new SpeechSynthesizer().GetInstalledVoices();
```

I only get one voice returned, the default Microsoft Anna Voice. but I can see all the installed voices in other text to speech application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found what the problem was. It turns out that when compiling the project to "Any CPU" (using Visual Studio 2008), the problem occurs. but when changed to x86, the problem doesn't appear anymore.

Comment: Ah.  You didn't mention this was 64-bit.

Comment: Eric, sorry about that. have you reproduced this problem ?

Comment: It's not a _problem_ per se; it's a byproduct of Win64 and .NET.  .NET apps (by definition) run as 64 bit apps on a 64-bit OS, and 32 bit apps on a 32-bit OS.  However, you can't load a 32-bit DLL into a 64-bit app.  All the Microsoft TTS engines ship in both 64-bit and 32-bit versions, but the Scansoft engines apparently only ship in 32-bit versions.  

Therefore, on a 64-bit application, you can only load the Microsoft TTS engines, and not the Scansoft engines.

And, therefore, if you mark your .NET app as 32-bit only, you can load both engines, and you see all your voices.

Answer (score 2):

I'm having troubles verifying this, but I believe that Scansoft's Jennifer voice is a SAPI 4.0 compliant voice; the Managed Speech API only works with SAPI 5.1 compliant voices.

Answer (score 2):

A recent update to Windows means the posted answer to this problem no longer works.

The new fix is:

The Speech files that are listed in the Registry Location...

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Speech_OneCore\Voices\Tokens\(filename)]
```

... all need to be copied to a new location:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Speech\Voices\Tokens\(filename)]
```

Note that the "Attributes" sub folder ie `[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Speech_OneCore\Voices\Tokens\(filename)\Attributes]`

also need to be copied to the new location, and edited so that it correctly reflects the name and path of the speech file it refers to.

Comment: Your solution is indeed show me now the voices when calling new Speechsyntheszier().GetInstalledVoices(), yet when selecting the voice it still uses the default voice. What did you mean with the attributes sub folder needed to be edited, I did not see how there is a path that does not reflect it?

Comment: So I figured it out what was not fully stated clearly: So what to do next is copy the speech files from %windir%\Speech_OneCore\Engines\TTS\ to the the %windir%\Speech\Engines\TTS\. Then it works.